# Activity not opening up in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have just started with android app development 
So i made an app in eclipse with android 10 as base (gingerbread)
Then i edited my main activity (main.java) to show up a menu with two options A)settings B)about
Then i created a resource at /res/xml/settings.xml and then made Prefs.java which uses addPreferencesFromResource() method..

But when i click on settings , i dont see anything..
I have also defined the activity in Android manifest of my app..

Here is my code :
//Prefs.java

```
package com.mhrsolanki2020.thecaller;

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }

}
```

//Main.java

```
package com.mhrsolanki2020.thecaller;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSecelted(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Prefs.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

//Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mhrsolanki2020.thecaller"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mhrsolanki2020.thecaller.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity android:name="com.mhrsolanki2020.thecaller.Prefs"
           android:label="@string/prefs_label"> </activity>  </application>

</manifest>
```

//  /res/xml/settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference 
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:title="@string/activation"
        android:summary="@string/activatoinSummary"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

// /menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_about"/>


</menu>
```

Comment: Are you sure you enter into onOptionsItemSecelted? Can you put a breakpoint and see?

Comment: `onOptionsItemSecelted` - typo - `onOptionsItemSelected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSecelted(MenuItem item){  // <-- typo onOptionsItemSelected
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Prefs.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: hey thanks.. that was a horrible mistake .. 
Eclipse does not recoginise such typos?? it should have given me an error right?

Comment: Because you didn't use `override`, Eclipse will treat it as a method which you have named.  It is perfectly legal but of course it won't be called. Add `override` and Eclipse will tell you that there is no such method to override.